# Emailing multiple data tables from different worksheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to extract a range of cells from two worksheets to the body of one email.

How do I include a range of cells from a second worksheet in my code?

I found a code online for a range of cells from one worksheet to appear in the body of the email.

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
    
    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
                 
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
          vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "subject"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would like to see two tables, one above the other with a space in between, in the body of one email.

Comment: Have a look at `Union`

Comment: I think Zac’s suggestion of a `Union` may be worth exploring.  Failing that, your options are limited.

Comment: I assume `RangeToHtml` is Ron De Bruin’s `RangeToHtml`.  This uses Microsoft’s `PublishObjects` to perform the conversion which produces a complete Html document.  If you had `.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng1) & RangetoHTML(rng2)`, you would have `<html><head> … <\head><body> … <\body><\html><html><head> … <\head><body> … <\body><\html>`.  You could try sending such an email to see what Outlook, Google Mail and so on made of it.  I think you would have to merge the two heads and the two bodies which I am confident would be very difficult.

Comment: Another option would be to perform the conversion from Excel to Html using VBA.  Providing your formatting was limited, this would not be too difficult.  What do I mean by “providing your formatting was limited”?  Borders are a nightmare because Excel and Html have different border models.  Cell level formatting is OK but in-cell formatting is a lot more difficult.  What sort of formatting do you want?  The code is not too complicated but every extra type of formatting increases the duration of the conversion.  What formatting do you want in your Html?

Comment: Thanks all

TonyDallimore - I actually have a pivot table, but easy enough to copy and paste special the pivot table on the same worksheet. The formatting I require for basic tables is borders on all cells and wrap text. Keeping in mind cell height and width will change each day as I will be refreshing the pivot table based on new data

0m3r - I will look into the below and keep you posted

Thanks again

Comment: Thanks 0m3r - that has worked a treat!! :) very happy!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Awesome- Please remember to mark the answer, check mark on the left- thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Just create another `Rng2` & `Function RangetoHTML2` and change all the references on `RangetoHTML2` in the `Function`*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
'    Set rng2 = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
'    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:G10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
'
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & "<BR><BR>" & RangetoHTML2(rng2)
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function


Function RangetoHTML2(rng2 As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng2.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML2 = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML2 = Replace(RangetoHTML2, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```